# How to use different methods to write code

Tags: c#

I have below function

```
 public static MyMainFunc(string nameOfCar)
 {
      string getNameOfCar = returnedNameOfCar(nameOfCar)
      string tyreNameOfCar= returnTyreNamesForCar(nameOfCar)
        // more logic 
 }
```

This is function for **returnNameOfCar**

```
  private static string returnNameOfCar(string carName)
    {
        string carName= "";
        if (carName== CarCollection.Audi.ToString())
        {
            carName= "Audi X";
        }
        else if (carName== CarCollection.BMW.ToString())
        {
            carName= "BMW Y";
        }

        return carName;
    }
```

I will have another function called as **returnTyreNamesForCar** returning some different code

```
private static string returnTyreNamesForCar(string carName)
    {
        string tyreName= "";
        if (carName== CarCollection.Audi.ToString())
        {
            tyreName= "Ceat";
        }
        else if (carName== CarCollection.BMW.ToString())
        {
            tyreName= "ABCD";
        }

        return tyreName;
    }
```

you can see code in function **returnNameOfCar** and **returnTyreNamesForCar ** are repeated.
Any idea how can i improve the code?

**Update**

CarCollection is Enum

```
    public enum CarCollection
{
    None = 0,
    Audi = 10,
    BMW = 11        
}
```

Comment: What is the `CarCollection`?

Comment: Can't you have a Car object that is filled with everything relative to it? (car brand, tyres, etc...)??

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Its an static Class holding list of different cars

Comment: Improve it with a database mb?

Comment: @NicoRiff no not unfortunately.

Comment: @KaiserKatze cant use database here as i have to read from c# class file only

Comment: use a tuple to reduce code..return name of car and tyre name

Comment: @James You can add extension method to get tyre and name, please share `CarCollection`

Comment: `string returnNameOfCar(string carName) { string carName= ""; [...] }` that wont even work. -- If you can't have a `Car` object (which would be the prefered way), maybe you can have static `Dictionary<string, string>` containers , where you can map the "carName" to either the "carName"(?) or the "tyreName"?

Comment: is `CarCollection.Audi` an enum? if so then why do you use strings to compare?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski sorry its an enum

Comment: will an audi car always have tires: `"Ceat"` ? or can it also have different ones?

Comment: @MongZhu it can have different ones

Comment: actually this question belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: " it can have different ones" up to now in your example it cannot, since the tires are dependent on the carname. You would need an entirely different concept of tire selection.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class called Car.

Add a static `Dictionary<CarCollection, Car>` field to your class.

Create instances from that class, filling it with relevant details, put them in the dictionary.

Add a static member to that class called GetCar, that will take in a member of the `CarCollection` and return the relevant car from the dictionary:

```cs
class Car
{
    private static Dictionary<CarCollection, Car> _availableCars = 
        new Dictionary<CarCollection, Car>()
        {
             {CarCollection.Audi, new Car("Ceat", "Audi X")},
             {CarCollection.BMW, new Car("ABCD", "BMW Y")},
        }

    static Car GetCar(CarCollection carName)
    {
        if(_availableCars.TryGetValue(carName, out var car))
        {
            return car;
        }
        // or throw an exception or something like that.
        return null; 
    }

    // Private constructor - 
    // don't let an outsider create an instance that's not in the dictionary.
    private Car(string tyreName, string carName)
    {
        TyreName = tyreName,
        CarName = carName
    }

    public string TyreName {get;}
    public string CarName {get;}
}
```

If you want to, you can make the car properties read/write, so whomever is using this code can set different values to them.

Comment: i will pass string of carname and then it should return me data. But in your case i hve to pass enum

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class representing the `Car` and return the object like:

```
public class Car
{
   public string CarName { get; set; }
   public string TyreName {get; set;}
}
```

and define a method which would return the `Car` with it's details :

```
private static Car GetCar(string carName)
{
    Car car = new Car();
    if (carName== CarCollection.Audi.ToString())
    {
        car.TyreName= "Ceat";
        car.CarName = "Audi X";
    }
    else if (carName== CarCollection.BMW.ToString())
    {
        car.TyreName = "ABCD";
        car.CarName = "BMW Y";
    }

    return car;
}
```

This might not be the best way, but this way you can avoid code duplication and for more you should read about factory design pattern in C# which can be applied to this problem to get different kind of objects of car.

Comment: `Tuple` makes more sense here

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski there are always multiple solutions to a problem :) yes that would also work

Comment: And if CarCollection was actually a collection (a dictionary) the code could be `if(CarCollection.TryGetValue(carName, out var car)) return car else return carName;`

Comment: @Magnus thanks for your valuable input here :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with use of collections, Enum and Linq expressions,

Define your Enum for list of car models as below(add n number car models):

```
public enum CarName
{
    None = 0,
    Audi = 1,
    BMW = 2
}
```

Define your domain class as below(all car property can be added as per need):

```
public class Car
{
    public CarName Name { get; set; }
    public string TyreName { get; set; }
    public int YearOfModel { get; set; }
}
```

Define your generic method which will return car details when you pass car model name(this can be modified as per need):

```
 public static Car GetCarDetails(string carName)
    {
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car(){ Name = CarName.Audi, TyreName = "CEAT", YearOfModel=2018},
            new Car(){ Name = CarName.BMW, TyreName = "ABCD", YearOfModel=2019}
        };

        return cars.Where(car => car.Name.ToString().Equals(carName)).Select(car => car).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

After defining all these, you can easily get car detail by just passing car model name alone:

```
 var carResult = GetCarDetails("Audi");

        Console.WriteLine("Car Name : " + carResult.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Car Tyre Name : " + carResult.TyreName);
```

Comment: if you define an enum, why would you still use a string as parameter to query for the name: `public static Car GetCarDetails(string carName)` ?

Comment: @MongZhu i will pass string so i get required data. how can i pass enum?

Comment: @MongZhu you need to pass string value to filter cars. please see the string parameter is used in lambda expression

Comment: if you need the exact enum name to be filtered then please use == instead of equals

Comment: usually one uses enums to increase code safety so that errors can be caught already at compile time. a string will be evaluated at runtime. If you already have an enum then why don't you pass an enum as parameter into the method?

Comment: @MongZhu i agree with your point. we can use enum, here the scenario i though car model name will be given as user (UI) input. everything will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it a bit with a `Switch` statement

```
public static MyMainFunc(string nameOfCar)
{
    string getNameOfCar = "", tyreNameOfCar = "";

    if (Enum.TryParse(nameOfCar, out CarCollection carType))
    {
        switch (carType)
        {
            case CarCollection.Audi:
                getNameOfCar = "Audi X";
                tyreNameOfCar = "Ceat";
                break;
            case CarCollection.BMW:
                getNameOfCar = "BMW Y";
                tyreNameOfCar = "ABCD";
                break;
        }
    }

    // more logic 
}
```